# Background-size: cover "spoofing" a taller div

Tags: html, css

Looking for a solution with as much browser support as possible.

I would like two background images of the exact same dimensions to be able to grow with the browser window (using `background-size: cover;`), but one of the divs has a fixed height.

Here is a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/uxfp6xos/

**-- Edit 2015/07/07**

I came up with an acceptable solution to this problem myself using [background-clip](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts). Internet Explorer 8 and below don't like it too much, but I can account for it, and it is a relatively small faction (support was one of my original requirements, so I felt I should call myself out on that aspect).

Updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uxfp6xos/2/

Comment: You can set multiple images in the background, just comma separate them. The same thing applies for background-size, position, etc.

Comment: @BuzzotheSplitter Wouldn't that just stack the two on top of one another? If they are the same pixel dimensions (300x300), and I want them to grow at the same rate but only show the top few pixels of one of them, how can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with an acceptable solution to this problem myself using [`background-clip`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts). Internet Explorer 8 and below don't like it too much, but I can account for it, and it is a relatively small faction (support was one of my original requirements, so I felt I should call myself out on that aspect).

Updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uxfp6xos/2/